# Preventative Maintenance on OS X / Running Onyx unattended

Tags: macos, maintenance

We have a Business Unit that has about 20 Mac's.  From time to time, when we need to solve strange issues that are not configuration issues. I will often run "Onyx", and unless there is an underlying hardware issue, it usually solves the problem.  I run the Automation, and have it rebuild just about all the caches.

Is there a best practice for preventing these cache issues from time to time, or a way to automate purging them to prevent issues in the first place?  The Business Unit manager would like to not have to open a support ticket with us, if this can be prevented by routine maintenance.

Comment: What does BU mean?

Comment: BU - Business Unit

Comment: I'm not understanding the exact issue here - what cache is getting corrupted that it needs to get rebuilt?  Also, is this normal to expect that the cache will become corrupted?  Please provide some specifics as it's much to vague to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, and it seems to be isolated to one user.  All we know is that this user keeps having performance and crashing issues, and after running Onyx, things are good for a while.  Then the same happens - lather, rinse, repeat...  We would like to automate what Onyx does, which seems to be purging of various caches, so I would like to automate that process.